# javascript date object different in the console and browser

Tags: javascript, date

I have an array of date object, I want to display in a range slider as ticks, but the date in the slider one day earlier than the value in the array.

console.log result:

[image]

slider result:

[image]

the function output to the slider:

```
const setMapLegend = function(dateLegend){
    // set min and max value in #sliderInput
    querySliderInput.min = dateLegend[0];
    querySliderInput.max = dateLegend[dateLegend.length - 1];

    // add <p> to queryTicks
    dateLegend.forEach((date)=>{
        const ptags = document.createElement('p');
        ptags.innerHTML = date;
        queryTicks.appendChild(ptags)

    })


}
```

I tried turn date object to string then parse it, but still the sanme

```
const setMapLegend = function(dateLegend){
    // set min and max value in #sliderInput
    querySliderInput.min = dateLegend[0].toString();
    querySliderInput.max = dateLegend[dateLegend.length - 1].toString();

    // add <p> to queryTicks
    dateLegend.forEach((date)=>{
        const ptags = document.createElement('p');
        console.log(date.toString());

        ptags.innerHTML = date.toString();
        queryTicks.appendChild(ptags)

    })


}
```

I would like to see the dates in the array not get changed. And would like to understand the data object in js behavior on this aspect: use an array of date object into a `forEach()` loop, you would see it changes the value. But why?

Comment: This is probably an issue with timezones.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you using an `<input type='range' />` for a slider?

Comment: I am. I have data for different dates based off use picked dates. I need to map the data for each date to a map. By using the slider, user can see the data changes for each day from the date they selected.

Comment: Make your range from 0 to 6 then onchange access your dates. `.min` and `.max` should not be instanceof Date.

Comment: "*the slider one day later than the value in the array*". Are you sure you don't mean one day **earlier**? There is no timezone where a timestamp of 00:00:00Z will give a date of the following day, however any timezone with a negative offset will have a date for one day earlier. The image seems to support one day earlier too.

Comment: @RobG yeah, we were probably talking about the same thing. I will edit it.

Comment: @StackSlave: ok I will try that